# video tag error event on ipad standalone web app does not work

Tags: javascript, ipad, html5-video, http-live-streaming, ios-standalone-mode

First to say sorry if I am asking already answered question, but I can't find it nor solve this at the moment.

I am developing an web application that is runned on iPad in a standalone mode.
There is an `<video>` tag and I am playing live stream videos with it, I think that this could be the problem since I did not tested error event on a static file.
My problem is that I can not bind onerror or error event to  tag so that if for some reason stream fail I can restart it.

My video tag looks like this:

```
<video id="video_tag" preload webkit-playsinline autoplay="autoplay" x-webkit-airplay="allow">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http_stream_url"></source>
</video>
```

I have tried to add `onerror="alert('error')"` on video tag directly, it did not worked.

I have tried to add an event listener to video tag directly `document.getElementById("video_tag").addEventListener('error', function(event) { alert('error'); }, true);` it did not worked.

I have tried to add event listener to source tag as somebody pointed that error event is triggered by source tag not video tag but it did not worked.

I also tried to put `onerror="alert('error')"` on source tag, did not worked.

Note that this is inside iPad > Safari > standalone mode > javascript web application > video tag > playing HLS (http live stream) stream

**EDIT:**
It does detect loading video stream fail but I need to detect when stream stops during playing and restart stream in that case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be listening for the `onstalled` event in the `video` element. A video element is a special kind of media element, and the list of events can be found at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp).

Keep in mind that the browser support is still fairly early, and not all the events are necessarily implemented. I would recommend creating a handler for all of the listed events and seeing if there is indeed an event being fired when the stream stops. I suspect that the `onreadystatechange` or `onsuspend` events could also help you.